# dropzonejs and jQuery File Upload presigned files not working

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, html, amazon-s3, shrine

I'm using **shrine** and **jQuery File Upload** to upload files directly to Amazon S3, but I'm having problems to make it work with **dropzone.js**.

When I use dropzone.js with no javascript everything works fine. But if I try to use options with dropzone.js the file is not uploaded to S3.

My code looks like this:

Upload.js

```
$(document).on("turbolinks:load", function () {

    $("[type=file]").fileupload({
        add: function (e, data) {
            console.log("add", data);
            data.progressBar = $('<div class="progress" style ="width: 300px"><div class="progress-bar"</div></div>').insertAfter(".loading");
            var options = {
                extension: data.files[0].name.match(/(\.\w+)?$/)[0], //file extension
                _: Date.now() //previene caching
            };

            $.getJSON("/files/upload/cache/presign", options, function (result) {
                console.log("presign", result);
                data.formData = result ['fields'];
                data.url = result['url'];
                data.paramName = "file";
                data.submit();
            });
        },
        progress: function (e, data) {
            console.log("progress", data);

            var progress = parseInt(data.loaded / data.total * 100, 10);
            var percentage = progress.toString() + '%';
            data.progressBar.find(".progress-bar").css("width", percentage).html(percentage);
        },
        done: function (e, data) {

            console.log("done", data);
            data.progressBar.remove();


            var document = {
                id: data.formData.key.match(/cache\/(.+)/)[1], // we have to remove the prefix part
                storage: 'cache',
                metadata: {
                    size: data.files[0].size,
                    filename: data.files[0].name.match(/[^\/\\]+$/)[0], // IE return full path
                    mime_type: data.files[0].type
                }
            };


            var form = $(this).closest("form");
            var form_data = new FormData(form[0]);
            form_data.append($(this).attr("name"), JSON.stringify(document));

            $.ajax(form.attr("action"), {
                contentType: false,
                processData: false,
                data: form_data,
                method: form.attr("method"),
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (response) {
                    /*var $img = $("<img/>", {src: response.image_url, width: 400});
                     var $div = $("<div/>").append($img);
                     $("#photos").append($div);*/
                }
            });

        }
    });
```

});

document.js

```
Dropzone.autoDiscover = false;
document.addEventListener("turbolinks:load", function () {
    new Dropzone("#myAwesomeDropzone", {
        paramName: "",
        maxFilesize: 2,
        dictDefaultMessage: 'Testing'
    });
});
```

html form

```
<%= form_for(@document, html: {multipart: true, class: 'dropzone', id: 'myAwesomeDropzone'}) do |f| %>
    <div class="fallback">
      <%= f.file_field :document %><br>
      <%= f.submit 'Upload my document' %>
    </div>
<% end %>
```

The only significant difference that I can see in the console (from when I use options with dropzonejs) is this `GET` from use dropzonejs with no javascript code.

```
Started GET "/files/upload/cache/presign?extension=.png&_=1500254726834" for 127.0.0.1 at 2017-07-16 21:25:26 -0400
```

I can't see what is the problem.

Comment: Why are plugins necessary? Are you trying to upload files dropped by user?

Comment: @guest271314 Yes, directly to S3.

Comment: What is purpose of `$.getJSON()` call? Could you not simply use a `<form>` to upload files?

Comment: Hmm for presign. I followed a tutorial from GoRails to accomplish the direct upload to S3.

Comment: What is "presign"?

Comment: from my understanding permit users without credentials upload and download files.

Comment: A "presign" is like a signature that the server-side part of the app generates from the AWS credentials, which the client needs to be able to upload a file directly to S3.